# Retrofit MaltformedJsonException expected at line - android

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I used `Facebook Login` in my app as registering. `Facebook API` part worked well and after I got parameters I saved them to session, too.

For second part, I create a user data in `MySQL` via `PHP Slim Framework.`

I posted body with Retrofit. After `user authentication` I got Facebook data perfectly.

Everything is good but somehow `Retrofit` works `onFailure` method instead of `onResponse` method. *(I got a little "user added" message in response)* And gives this error(below)

**Debug Mode Screenshot:** [Click to See](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWPwh.jpg)

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

CallbackManager callbackManager;
TextView text;
Button button;
ImageView image;
ProgressDialog mDialog;

String accessToken;

//SESSION
String user_email;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    goIfTokenExist();

    //
    text = findViewById(R.id.text);
    image = findViewById(R.id.image);
    //

    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email", "user_birthday", "user_friends"));

    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            mDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            mDialog.setMessage("Retrieving data...");
            mDialog.show();

            accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken();

            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                    mDialog.dismiss();
                    getData(object);
                    goIfTokenExist();
                }
            });

            //Graph API
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,birthday");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {

        }
    });

    if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
        text.setText(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getUserId());
    }

}

public void getData(JSONObject obj) {
    try {
        URL profile_picture = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/" + obj.getString("id") + "/picture?width=250&height=250");
        Glide.with(this).load(profile_picture.toString()).into(image);

        text.setText(
                "ID: " + obj.getString("id") + "\n" +
                "NAME: " + obj.getString("name") +
                "EMAIL: " + obj.getString("email") +
                "BIRTHDAY: " + obj.getString("birthday")
        );

        //SAVE SESSIONS
        editor.putString("facebook_id", obj.getString("id"));
        editor.putString("facebook_email",obj.getString("email"));
        editor.putString("facebook_name",obj.getString("name"));
        editor.putString("facebook_birthday",obj.getString("birthday"));
        editor.putString("facebook_username",""+obj.getString("name").replaceAll("\\s+","").toLowerCase());
        editor.commit();

        UserFacebook userNew = new UserFacebook(
                obj.getString("id"),
                obj.getString("email"),
                obj.getString("name"),
                obj.getString("birthday"),
                obj.getString("name").replaceAll("\\s+","").toLowerCase());

        API_Service service = Client.getRetrofitInstance().create(API_Service.class);

        Call<UserFacebook> userFacebookCall = service.addFacebookUser(userNew);
        userFacebookCall.enqueue(new Callback<UserFacebook>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<UserFacebook> call, Response<UserFacebook> response) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<UserFacebook> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "was wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public boolean isLoggedIn() {
    AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
    return accessToken != null;
}

public void goIfTokenExist() {
    //FORWARD TO HOME IF TOKEN IS VALID
    if (isLoggedIn() == true) {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ForwardDeneme.class));
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "no token!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}}
```

**API_Service (interface)**

```
public interface API_Service {
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST("api/user/add")
Call<UserFacebook> addFacebookUser(@Body UserFacebook userFacebook);}
```

**Client**

```
public class Client {

private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
private static String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.1.102/myWebsite/public/index.php/";

private Client() {}

public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance() {
    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = new retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

    }
    return retrofit;

}}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: String your receive from the back end is not valid json and cannot be parsed to `UserFacebook` model. Print actual response and check what's wrong with this

Comment: Thanks for answer. Yeah its not like that model actually. In fact, I used that model to post, in response there is like "success" message. How can I reach that simple success message without using that model?

Comment: Use `String` as return type

Comment: I tried to change like this, but doesn't let me to do that, where should I change exactly?

`public void onResponse(Call<UserFacebook> call, Response<String> response) {`

Answer (score 0):

Change the Response from call, from UserFacebook to String or UserFacebook need a String parameter called user_added (depending on the json you are receiving)

Comment: You mean this?
It doesn't let me to do that. Can you show which part exactly?

`public void onResponse(Call<UserFacebook> call, Response<String> response)`

Comment: You have to change Call<UserFacebook> to Call<String> aswell but keep UserFacebook as body for the request of corse